# Toggling number of table rows in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

Consider having 35 rows and by default you have to show 10 rows upon clicking toggle it will show 35 rows and vice versa.

Right now I am doing like this

toggling the number of rows with a boolean `isCardOpen` by default it is false

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of total_items;let i = index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isCardOpen; else showFullList">
       <ng-container *ngIf="i<10">
           <td> My table data comes here </td>
        </ng-container>
    <ng-container>
    <ng-template #showFullList>
       <td> My table data again comes here but without if condition</td>
    <ng-template>
</tr>
```

I am able to get my desired output but is there anyother way, I meant I am having the same table data twice i.e in `showFullList` template and inside `*ngIf="i<10"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your ngIf to `*ngIf="i < 10 || isCardOpen"`, so when `isCardOpen = false`, only the first ten items show. If `isCardOpen = true`, then all item show (regardless of index).

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of total_items; let i = index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="i < 10 || isCardOpen"></ng-container>
</tr>
```

---

As an alternative, you could add a property to each item, and toggle that item's property to render/unrender with ngIf.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of total_items">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.isOpen"></ng-container>
</tr>
```